# Copy package to a specific directory with customized ISO

Tags: iso, remastersys

I have a *customized* Ubuntu ISO, where I have all my required packages being installed, from the `/pool/extras/` directory. Now, I want to be able to *copy* one of the packages (`.deb`) from this `/pool/extras` directory and save it to *another location*, say to the home directory of a user that I know exists (`/home/myuser/`).
I tried adding this in the *preseed*

```
d-i   preseed/late_command string if [ -f /media/cdrom/pool/extras/mypkg.deb ]; then cp -f /media/cdrom/pool/extras/mypkg.deb /home/myuser; fi
```

But this didn't seem to work!, is this approach correct ? or is there any other way that I can get the package (at a later stage, maybe) from `/pool/extras` ?

Comment: Just wondering how you made the customized iso? Almost all the guides I've seen are prohibitively harder than a simple install script run from another drive (at least once or twice)

Comment: @Xen2050, Actually that _hard_ part was already solved by a co-worker. And I'm not very sure of the innards of it :(

Comment: That's the best way to solve a problem sometimes, get someone else to do it... kind of like askubuntu! :)

Comment: But with this one, I don't have a choice, I tried all I could, and now  seeking help here.

Comment: You might be missing [`in-target`](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/apbs05.html.en#preseed-hooks).

Answer (score 1):

I have at least a suggestion for you. I know that this works, because I work on a project with Ubuntu 14.4 and this mechanism works for me.

First the preesed.cfg preseed-lat command

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
cd /target; \
wget http://sub.webserver.domain/directory/script; \
chmod +x ./script; \
chroot ./ ./script; \
rm -f ./script
```

The file that we call script here contains the code that gats executed while the
installation:

something like

```
wget http://sub.webserver.tdl/dir/run -O /etc/profile.d/run.sh
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/run.sh
```

as you see this approach requires a webserver. If you have an ISO as your case ju can store both files in the root of your ISO and use the following

```
  d-i preseed/run string script
```

In this case the script has to be in the same directory then the preseed.cfg

In the example above the script file juust copies run.sh to the profile.d directory in wich every sh file is being executed when a user is logging in.

Depending on what you want to do you can either use the script file itself to copy your files with sh-shell commands or use the sh file in profile.d with bash after the user has loggd in and delet it if thae actions are done.

Comment: where I install the package, there is no access to internet. Also  in my case the script is a single line string.

Comment: You can use the script file to copy the package from the cd Rom to the user's HOME and than run sumo dog -I 《package.deb》 without the 《》

Comment: Take a look here. https://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/example-preseed.txtadd your package in the individual package section like they do in the example file

Comment: which section from the example are you referring to? BTW, my package is already being installed, but what I'm trying to do is, to _save_ (or _archive_) a copy of that package in a separate location.

Comment: So you can just use a cp - r path to package   /target/opt and than mv /target/opt/filename.deb /somepath

Comment: /target is the alias for cd /

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the ISO way didnt work for me, so the workaround I used is, via `dpkg` :

In my `.deb` package, in the `postinst` script (`bash`), I added a section like:

```
MYPKG=$(find $PWD -name mypkg.deb)
cp -f $MYPKG /home/myuser
```

surprisingly enough, when I logged the path, it was indeed `/media/cdrom/pool/extras/mypkg.deb`
(as used in the `late_command` string!) :(

Not sure why it didn't work via `d-i preseed/late_command`